# Class a static method with parameter from a class which's name is stored in a variable

Tags: php, oop

Basically I'm trying to do this

```
$className = 'myClass';

$className::myMethod($aParameter);
```

but I'm getting a unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM, however I read that I could replycate

```
$className::myMethod();
```

with

```
call_user_func(array($className, 'myMethod'));
```

the only problem now is that I really need to pass that paremeter, any idea on how can I get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the parameter. [`call_user_func()`](http://www.php.net/call_user_func) accepts an unlimited additional parameters that it will pass on to the called function.

```
call_user_func(array($className, 'myMethod'), $aParameter);
```

Comment: I see! I was getting really confused regarding the parameter on class_user_func, i was indeed passing the parameter in the array().